# Get value from one table and use it for another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

images contains the following colls: imageID and imagePath.

articles contains: articleID, imageID.

I would like to get the imagePath data using single mysql query when I know the articleID.

I searched in similar questions but I couldn't find something helpfull...

Comment: It's called a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a JOIN operation.

One way (out of several ways) to do this in a single query:

```
SELECT i.imagePath
  FROM images i
  JOIN articles a
    ON a.imageID = i.imageID
 WHERE a.article_id = 'foo'
```

(This isn't the only way, there are several other queries that will return an equivalent result.)

Note that if there are multiple rows in the `images` table that have a matching value in `imageID`, the query will return multiple rows. If a matching row does not exist, the query will return zero rows.

An `OUTER JOIN` operation can be used to return rows from `articles`, even when matching rows do not exist in the `images` table. For example:

```
SELECT a.articleID
     , i.imagePath
  FROM articles a
  LEFT
  JOIN images i
    ON i.imageID = a.imageID
 WHERE a.article_id = 'foo'
```